# How to prove that a minimum / maximum exists in a given interval?

Tags: calculus, continuity, maxima-minima

Consider a continuous real-valued function $f$ over the interval $[a, b]$. I am trying to prove that there exists at least one absolute max and one absolute min.

More formally:

$$\exists c,d \in [a,b] : \forall x \in [a,b], ~f(c) \leq f(x) \leq f(d)$$

I don't even know where to begin because it just seems so obviously true. How could you *not* have a max or min?

Comment: "At least one absolute maximum?"  How can you have more than one?  Also, if the interval is not closed, or the function is not continuous, then there needn't be a maximum, so there is definitely something to prove here.

Comment: This is the Extreme Value Theorem.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem.

Comment: @saulspatz A periodic function?

Comment: @saulspatz I assume "more than one absolute maximum" would refer to the situation in which the absolute maximum is attained at more than one location.  (The word "maximum" is widely used both to refer to the largest value of the function, and to the point at which the value is attained.)

Comment: @saulspatz in a surjective function, you could have more than  one maximum. E.g. $f=x^2, x \in[-2,2]$, you can have both $2$ or $-2$ as $d$

Comment: @Nobody You can have one maximum value that is assumed multiple times.

Comment: @saulspatz The maxium isn't $f(d)$, it's $d$

Comment: @mweiss I don't think I've ever seen that usage in over 50 years of reading math.  I've always seen "$f$ takes it maximum at $x$, not "The maximum of $f$ is $x$," but live and learn.

Comment: @saulspatz How about:  "Q:  Find the absolute maximum...    A: The maximum is $(3,15)$."  Is that so unusual?

Comment: @mweiss I had to read it twice to understand it, but that may just be me.  I would write the maximum is $f(3)=15,$  but if the other usage is common, it's fine with me.

Answer (score 2):

It is a very important theorem.

It has to do with both the compactness of [a,b] and the continuity of your function.

There is much more going on than it seems at the first glance.

The conclusion will not necessarily be true if the interval  is not closed or the function is not continuous.

For example $f(x)=1/x$ on $(-1,1)$ does not have an absolute maximum or minimum.

Comment: What about the piecewise function $f(x) = -1$ for $x<0$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \geq 0$?, over interval $[-1, 1]$?

Comment: Yes, this example shows that the converse of the theorem is not true.I have edited my solution.

Answer (score 1):

First show that $f([a,b])$ is bounded: Assume that if it were not, choose $(x_{n})\subseteq[a,b]$ such that $f(x_{n})>n$. Now pick a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})\subseteq(x_{n})$ such that $f(x_{n_{k}})>n_{k}$, this will violate the continuity of $f$.

Now take $M=\sup f([a,b])$. Assume that $M\notin f([a,b])$, consider that $g=1/(M-f)$, then $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and hence bounded by the previous argument. But $f(\eta_{n})\rightarrow M$ for some $(\eta_{n})\subseteq[a,b]$, then $g(\eta_{n})\rightarrow \infty$, a contradiction.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance but I am not familiar with some of this notation, what is $(x_{n})\subseteq[a,b]$, $(x_{n_{k}})\subseteq(x_{n})$, etc?

Comment: The sequence in $[a,b]$.

Comment: Is it any arbitrary sequence of points in $[a,b]$ or literally all the points in a row (infinitely many)?

Comment: The points $x_{n}\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x_{n})>n$. $(x_{n_{k}})$ is a subsequence of $(x_{n})$, that is, for example, $(x_{n_{k}})=(x_{2},x_{3},x_{5},x_{10},...)$.

Comment: I'm sure this answer is correct but I feel like it's skipping over a lot of stuff. I don't understand what $n$ is or what these sequences actually look like. Is $n$ just some arbitrary boundary, and we're saying we should be able to find a sequence of points where all of them are $>n$ (i.e. the points "above" the bound), and then we pick some subset of these points, and somehow this violates continuity? I don't really understand what this is saying.

Comment: Actually I have assumed that $f$ has no upper bound. Then there is a point $x_{1}\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x_{1})>1$. There is a point $x_{2}\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x_{2})>2$, and proceed in this way. Then Bolzano Theorem says that the sequence $(x_{n})$ has a convergent subsequence, say, $x_{n_{k}}\rightarrow x_{0}\in[a,b]$. With $f(x_{n_{k}})>n_{k}$, then taking $k\rightarrow\infty$, by the continuity of $f$, then $f(x_{0})=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f(x_{n_{k}})\geq\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}n_{k}=\infty$, a contradiction.

Comment: I am still not getting it, unfortunately I think it's over my head

Comment: Sorry, then I really don't know how to help.

Comment: I am doing a little more reading, so basically we are trying to prove by contradiction? If we want to prove $\exists d \in [a,b] : \forall x \in [a,b], ~f(x) \leq f(d)$ we can show its negation is false, $\forall d \in [a,b] : \exists x \in [a,b], ~f(x) > f(d)$, so for any $d$ we pick we can find $f(x)$ greater than $f(d)$, correct?

Comment: Yes, almost. The strategy that I was doing is that, first claim that it is bounded, and then it attains the least upper bound. I use contradiction in both reasoning.

Comment: Why do we assume there is a $f(x_1) > 1$, $f(x_2) > 2$, etc? Where within the confines of the problem for $\forall d \in [a,b] : \exists x \in [a,b], ~f(x) > f(d)$ are we allowed to posit the existence of these values? Isn't this assuming $f(d) = 1$ exists, $f(d) = 2$ exists, etc?

Comment: No, no, I am not claiming there is $d$ such that $f(d)=1$, $f(d)=2$. Rather, if you go by negative like for all $d\in[a,b]$, there is an $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)>f(d)$, then we can continue nothing about this strategy. My strategy is that, first claim that the range $f([a,b])$ has an upper bound.